# Core Data Structure - avoiding circular reference?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I just wanted to validate my data structure.
It seems a bit convoluted to me, maybe it can be simplified?

[image: Snapshot from Core Data Model Editor]

- Questions are grouped into chapters.
- For each question, only one answer per session is possible.
- The purpose is to be able to compare / analyze answers to the same questions (by different users or by the same users at different times, i.e. with different sessions).
- A template, being a collection of chapters & questions, should not have to be replicated, if chapters and questions are the same.
- (That would be necessary if Answer did not have a relationship to Session.)
- Is the relationship from Answer back to Session the right strategy?
- What else would you improve to simplify the model?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Follow-up clarification:

- The Answer is not static (e.g. "right" answer, "solution"), but some text the user inputs. It is more like a "questionnaire" than a "quiz". The answer has quantitative attributes that can be analyzed.
- As stated, one question can have only one answer within a session. Because questions can indirectly belong to more than one session (via `(NSSet*) question.chapter.template.sessions`), they could have more than one answers and thus need a to-many relationship.
- The typical scenario: User starts a new session with a certain template and fills out the answers. Then he can look at the analysis of the results and compare those with the results of other sessions that use the same template.

**EDIT 2**

The snapshot of the data model including attributes

[image: Snapshot of data model including attributes]

Comment: It's difficult to give feedback without really knowing all the "rules of the game" but for starters: 1. How do you get the questions asked per session if an answer can belong to multiple questions? 2. Assuming you need to know which answer is correct vs possible for a certain question (like for multiple choice) - I do not see how exactly that tis mapped 3. is all this dynamic or static ? bec I do not see an issue of circular dependencies with static at all. Also need to know the most critical access scenarios to optimize this...

Comment: I edited my question to clarify. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: if **you** can handle in your code that you won't never run into an infinite loop when you work with the datas, the `Core Data` can handle such structure without any problem, so you should worry about yourself only.

Comment: @holex Thanks - any simplification suggestions?

Comment: i.e. you can store in two separated entities _1._ the sessions' templates and _2._ the chapters' templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the really helpful effort by the part of @holex - the best way still seems to be to stick with my design. The simplifications I had hoped for have not materialized.

Answer (score 1):

honestly, this is what I would do instead of your structure, but I don't know what the purpose of the each entity because I'm not able to find out from their simple names.

**this is just an idea to resolve the loop**.

you can still reach all *templates* and all *answers* from the *session*, not directly but it does not make your life much harder.

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

at the first and second sight, for me, it seems the `Session` entity is just an extra entity only here. honestly you would not need it, if you concatenate with the `Template` (aka *Questionnaire*) entity.

you have to add a *many-to-many* relationship between the `Template` and `User` (you can do it, don't worry about it). using this way, from each template you can reach all answers as well, and you won't have any loop.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this **beautiful** answer. Thanks for taking the trouble to do the graphics! Unfortunately, this would not work because *Chapters* need to be reused. If they have a to-one relationship to *Session*, I have to duplicate them for each new session. That's what I am doing now - resulting in lots of duplication and huge data transfers.

Comment: it would be great to see the `attributes` as well because they could give clear picture about which causes the loop, and honestly I don't see the point of the `session` entity. :(

Comment: The attributes would only confuse the picture. The loop can only be caused by relationships anyway, not by attributes. The *Session* entity is necessary because you want to be able to go through all the questions, say, every three months for one year. So you have four data points (*Answers*) for each question. That is what the session is for (plus keeping track of date, project, language, etc.).

Comment: and why do you need the both `sessions<-->>template` and `chapters<-->>template` relationship? if you can drop one of them you would solve the loop-problem easily as well.

Comment: Perhaps you misread: it's `session<<--->template` and `chapter<<--->template`, not `session<--->>template` and `chapter<--->>template`. The template is simply a collection of chapters with questions, and it has a title, introduction etc.

Comment: no, I read the relationship correctly, but this is not the point. the point is in that case why do you need a relationship between the `session` and `template`? the `session` is independent from the `chapter` and it seem not too logical the `session` depends on the `template` of `chapter`. what is the logic behind this relationship?

Comment: Here is the logic: a template is, say, like a questionnaire. It consists of a title, author, introduction; chapters; questions. One session obviously must be based on one template / questionnaire. Now you can fill out the *same* questionnaire several times, by creating sessions with the *same* template. If you skipped template and had a link from session to chapters, you would have to replicate the title, author, introduction etc. in the questions, creating redundant data. Clear?

Comment: see? :) this is why I told you it would be great to know the attributes, because the attributes define the current entity and without them it is very hard to analyse the purpose of the entities, and the points of the relationships between them. could you share the whole structure? it is possible you should redesign some entities to solve the loop, you've said you need all relationships so now I'm 100% sure the loop is definitely caused by bad architecture of the entities. :(

Comment: I added the attributes to the question.

Comment: Sorry, that won't work. First, I am replicating potentially substantial data (the original attributes of *Template*) for each *Session*. More significantly, if *chapters* is a one-to-many relationship, all *Chapters* and *Questions* have to be replicated as well (this is what I wanted to avoid). If *chapters* is many-to-many, there is no way to attribute an *Answer* to a specific *Template*. Maybe a solution would be to include the attribute *uid* in *Answer*, but it would also be a replication and be the same as a classic foreign key and obliterate the relationship mechanism of Core Data.

Comment: I'm always using the following way when I design the data structure: first I define all of the queries what I'll need in the application, I organise them and then I build the database for easy implementing all queries. I have had no problem in case of huge applications as well. sometimes I worked with 80-100 different entities / tables to build the really complex structure. I don't know your process but this way helps me in every time to keep clear and consistent the architecture of database. maybe it helps you as well. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am able to do all my queries. The object graph programming is not as simple as usual, but I guess it's OK. I had the app working alright already, now I need to make it scalable to 100.000s of records, so duplicate data has to be avoided. Cheers.

Comment: if you can do every queries without problem, you should not worry about your original plan of database because that is the good structure for your application — the `CoreData` can handle the loops well during the storage process.